# Newer constructs are recommended

Tags: html, css, jsp

The World Wide Web consortium now regards the tag  as outdated. Newer constructs are recommended.What's new?

Comment: can you be more specific about what are you asking? if you can post the source of your doubt, it will help a lot to give you an answer

Answer (score 2):

You are probably referring to a message from some authoring software, presumably by Microsoft (it uses phrases like this). Consult the documentation of the software for explanations of its messages. But beware that messages like this may be misleading or outdated. They typically point to [deprecation of elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/conform.html#deprecated) in the HTML 4.01 specification, which is itself partly dated (the W3C is mostly rather silent about it and talks more about HTML5, though it’s still just a working draft).

It depends on the element how it can be replaced by newer constructs, typically some other element and the use of CSS. For a quick (and dirty?) reference, check out my [Mapping presentational HTML to CSS](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html2css.html). You might also consider using whatever tags do the job you want to get done, without worrying too much about flagging things as “outdated”, “deprecated”, or “obsolete” (which is often just an ideological position, though sometimes with practical grounds too); see my [HTML Anarchist’s Leaflet](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/pragmatic-html.html8).